# ScrollView acting weird when i put tableview inside scrollview and tableview scrolling is disable

Tags: swiftui

I was trying to make a custom list. And its acting weird if we add Encapsulated VStack in scrollView and scrollview contain tableview.

Comment: Show code, show problem, describe what you're going to achieve.

Comment: There is no TableView in SwiftUI. Only Lists and Forms. I assume this question is related to UIKit UITableView.